# Git push automatically update all submodules

Tags: git

I searched and searched for an automatically way of updating(synchronizing) all submodules when pushing.

I have the main project, e.g: test

Another project, e.g: *test1*

Inside test I have 'added'  submodule called test1 -> which links to outside project *test1*.
OK, all good.

So I will clone my main project TEST, it will come with test1 submodule empty. I will run `git submodule init` and `git submodule update --remote --recursive` to bring me the latest from test1.

All good! Now I have the latest revision(of files / and files ) of submodule test1 on my local copy.

Now, I'm modifying something in test1 locally and I want to **push** it back.
When I hit: `Git branch -a` on test1 submodule, I have something like this:

```
$ git branch -a
* (HEAD detached from f417982)
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

OK, I will checkout to master and merge between master and revision number to include my 'modifications' in test1 master branch.

So I MERGED and now it asks me for push. OK, I will PUSH.
The files are updated(pushed) ONLY in *test1* project, I want them to be automatically updated also in test/test1 submodule...

Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how familiar you are with git submodules, so I will explain general behavior first, since it might be helpful for other readers as well.

You have two separate repositories, `test` and `test1`.
`test1` is added as submodule to `test`.

This leads to the following situation:

- `test` knows about `test1`
- `test1` does **not** know about `test`
- You and other developers can commit to `test1` without having `test` checked out.
- `test1` has its own git history and commits, running `git status` in the `test` repo folder will show different reuslts, than in the `test1` subfolder.
- You can not commit to two repos at once and share a commit.

So in order to update something the submodule `test1` and use it in the main repo `test` you have to do the following steps:

1. Make you adjustments in the submodule an commit.
   *Make sure you are in the submodule's folder.*
2. Run `git status` in you main repo.
   It should say `modified: test1 (new commits)`
3. Commit and push this modification in your main repo `test`.

Further explanation:

- Your commit in step 1 only adjusts the history of your `test1` repo.
- Since it is a submodule of `test`, the main repo will show a local modification, because it checks that something changed.
- The main repo `test` only has a pointer to a certain commit of the submodule `test1`.
- The local pointer is update whenever you change the HEAD of you submodule.
- The make sure other developer update their pointer (and change their submodule's HEAD) you have to push the updated pointer, as described in step 3.

Hope this helps.

---

**Update:** If you have submodule `test1` checked out twice, e.g. in (a) `test/test1` and (b) `test1-alone` and make modifications to **(b)**, the steps are a bit different:

1. Fetch or pull `test/test1` to get the changes pushed in `test1-alone`.
2. Make sure HEAD of `test/test1` points to the desired commit.
3. Run `git status` in you main repo.
   It should say `modified: test1 (new commits)`
4. Commit and push this modification in your main repo `test`.

The last two steps are the same as above.
In general:

1. Adjust HEAD of your submodule (make sure it points to a pushed commit).
2. Commit updated pointer in you main repo.

---

**Update 2:** If you have submodule test1 checked out twice, e.g. in (a) test/test1 and (b) test1-alone and make modifications to **(a)**, the steps are a bit different:

1. Commit and push your changes in `test/test1`.
2. `fetch` or `pull` remote changes in `test1-alone`

This has nothing to do with the submodule behavior. It's exactly the same behavior, as if you would check out `test1` in two different locations, like `folderA/test1` and `folderB/test1`

Comment: Hello Florieger, in little words: when I push new modifications to test/test1 (which test1 is a submodule) and linked to test1(an outside project), I want those modifications to be "merged" also in test1(the outside project)..

Comment: @Manfeld Take a look at my updated answer, Update 2.